# Installing theme in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: themes, 17.10, tar

I'm trying to install new theme on my Ubuntu 17.10

```
karan@KARAN-VAIO:~/Downloads$ sudo tar -xf Ant-Dracula.tar /usr/share/themes/
tar: /usr/share/themes: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

and this..

```
karan@KARAN-VAIO:/usr/share/themes$ ls
Ambiance  Default  Emacs  HighContrast  Radiance  Raleigh
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a `-C`:

```
sudo tar -xf Ant-Dracula.tar -C /usr/share/themes/
```

`man tar` says

```
   -C, --directory=DIR
          Change to DIR before performing any operations.  This  option  is  order-sensitive,
          i.e. it affects all options that follow.
```